# How to make error message for this code

Tags: linux, bash, macos, indexing

```
#!/bin/bash

my_array=(red orange green)
value='green'

for i in "${!my_array[@]}"; do
if [[ "${my_array[$i]}" = "${value}" ]]; then
   echo "${i}";
fi
done
```

This code will print the index of a value in an array, How can i improve it to print error message if the Entry was not in the array

Comment: Do you want to print all indexes if there is more occurrences of your value in the array or is one enough?

Answer (score 2):

You can add a flag variable,
cleared before the loop,
set when the value is found,
and print the error message after the loop if the flag is still empty.

```
found=
for i in "${!my_array[@]}"; do
    if [[ "${my_array[$i]}" = "${value}" ]]; then
        echo "${i}"
        found=1
    fi
done

if [ ! "$found" ]; then
    echo Error: no such value in the array: $value
fi
```

Alternatively,
you could use an associative array to keep an index of the values and their positions in the array:

```
my_array=(red orange green)

declare -A index
for ((i = 0; i < ${#my_array[@]}; i++)); do
    index[${my_array[$i]}]=$i
done

local value=$1

if [ "${index[$value]}" ]; then
    echo "${index[$value]}"
else
    echo Error: no such value in the array: $value
fi
```